# Is it possible to reverse the effect of bleach bit to fix my problem about an oversized folder?

Tags: 14.04, files, bleachbit

Is it possible to reverse the effect of bleach bit?

What happened:

- Last week I installed Bleach Bit and ran it for the first time on my newly installed Ubuntu system. I noticed that it was doing its thing and that it was filling up my computer's hard drive and slowing it down. So I left it and went to sleep (I left it over night).
- When i checked it in the morning the Bleach Bit window was dark like a not responding window. So I didn't do anything. I left it on and running and went to work.
- When I got back from work, it was still dark and not responding. and I had 198 GB free out of a 640 GB hard drive. I don't have a lot of files on the system, only about 90 GB tops would have bee occupied.
- I powered off and turned it on again. Now I am just left with the 198 GB.

What I have tried so far:

1. Run Bleach Bit again but it always freezes and never completes.
2. Uninstall and reinstall Bleach Bit and ran again.

I only ran Bleach Bit on it because I thought that it would fix the issue (but it didn't). Instead what I have now is over sized folders and I cannot see the files that are occupying this space.

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: So instead of freeing up disk space, it actually started occupying more?

Answer (score 1):

Bleach bit creates temporary large files.

Are not deleted if interrupte.

Load the file manager with administrator permissions.(gksu - kdesu - sudo su)

Press Control + H

Find the files and delete them.